# Local datastore not persisted between application restarts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am running the GuestBook example from [Google Developer CodeLab](https://sites.google.com/site/gdevelopercodelabs/app-engine/java-codelab).

When adding an entry, it shows up in the list of greetings and in the [local datastore](http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin)

So far so good...

When I restart the application, however, only *some* of the entries still exist, while *some* disappear entirely, both from the list maintained by my app, and from the local datastore, as seen in above link.

I am using the google plugin for Eclipse to develop and test my application.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you're passing the `--clear-datastore` argument, either directly or through the launcher, to the `dev_appserver`. Another possibility is that something is erasing your temporary directory (such as on reboot), which is the default location for the dev_appserver's local datastore.

I don't know what would cause only some entities to disappear, and it's impossible to say without seeing your code. I also don't know what you mean by "the list maintained by [your] app".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I would think that a `--clear-datastore` argument, would erase ALL values, not just some.

The local datastore files, in the *appengine-generated* folder, are still there when I restart, and again, I would think that all values would disappear, if these files were erased.

The code is unmodified from the google codelab example (link provided in question).
The list maintained by my app, is just the list returned by the query and printed out:

```
<%
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    String query = "select from " + Greeting.class.getName();
    List<Greeting> greetings = (List<Greeting>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
    if (greetings.isEmpty()) {
%>
<p>The guestbook has no messages.</p>
<%
    } else {
        for (Greetingg : greetings) {
            if (g.getAuthor() == null) {
%>
<p>An anonymous person wrote:</p>
<%
            } else {
%>
<p><b><%= g.getAuthor().getNickname() %></b> wrote:</p>
<%
            }
%>
<blockquote><%= g.getContent() %></blockquote>
<%
        }
    }
    pm.close();
%>
```