# My GAE python development datastore is never persisted to a file

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7, eclipse-indigo

I have just started using GAE (Python 2.7 SDK 1.6.4) , I have set up a 
simple test project using Pydev (latest version) in eclipse (indigo) 
on Windows XP (SP3).

It all works fine, my app can record data in the datastore and the blobstore 
and then retrieve it, but when I stop the development server and start 
it again the data in the datastore is lost. This is not the case for 
the blobstore which is retaining blobs fine and I can see the 
blobstore folder that gets created in C:\Temp

I did the sensible thing and look back through old posts and found 
that most people who have this problem solve it by changing the 
location of the datastore file, so I used the following parameters;

```
--datastore_path="${workspace_loc}/myproject/datastore" 
--blobstore_path="${workspace_loc}/myproject/blobstore" 
"${workspace_loc}/myproject/src"
```

I moved the blobstore at the same time as you can see.

The blobstore still works, and now the blobstore folder is created in 
myproject folder as expected. The datastore file is still not created 
however, and when I stop and restart the development server the data 
is still lost.

The dev server startup logs include the following entry

```
WARNING  2012-04-20 10:49:04,513 datastore_file_stub.py:513] Could not 
read datastore data from C:\myworkspace\myproject\datastore
```

So I know it is trying to create the datastore in the correct place.

Finally I lifted the whole eclipse workspace folder and copied it to 
another computer with exactly the same setup except it is running 
Windows 7 instead of Windows XP.

Everything works fine there - both the datastore file and blobstore 
folder are now created where I expect them to be.

I have set up eclipse, python, gae, my project and my eclipse launch 
file in exactly the same way on two computers, it works on one  and 
not the other. Maybe XP is something to do with it but to be honest I 
think that's unlikely.

The only other clue I have come up with is that a recent change to the 
GAE development server stopped writing to the datastore file after 
every change and only flushes on exit, this problem may be closely related to mine;

[App Engine local datastore content does not persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047315/app-engine-local-datastore-content-does-not-persist)

However adding the following to my code did not help at all.

```
from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver 
import atexit 
atexit.register(dev_appserver.TearDownStubs)
```

So it's not down to incorrect termination sequence either as far as I 
can tell although it may be that I was just added it in the wrong place (I'm am new to python).

Anyway I am stumped and I would be really grateful for suggestions you 
guys can come up with.

Comment: You've probably seen the other post saying that the datastore is only flushed to disk on proper termination.  Most likely eclipse is terminating dev_appserver "poorly".  For example, if it just terminated the process (ie the same way as killing it in Task Manager) it won't flush data to disk properly.

Try running dev_appserver.py from the commandline without eclipse, quit with Ctrl-C.  This should save properly.

I don't know how eclipse shuts down the python process, but your solution is likely in that direction.

Comment: Try installing the latest gae SDK.

as in the case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998936/app-engine-datastore-auto-clears-every-time-project-runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7244 and a bug. Hopefully a fix will be available soon.

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

--storage_path=...

Path at which all local files (such as the Datastore, Blobstore files, Google Cloud Storage Files, logs, etc) will be stored, unless overridden by --datastore_path, --blobstore_path, --logs_path, etc.

found at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?csw=1